# How to use SearchFilter using a dbRef with Api_Platform?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine, dbref

When I have a document property using a dbRef - relation like this:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne (
 *     discriminatorMap={
 *       "post"=Post::class
 *     },
 *     defaultDiscriminatorValue="post",
 *     storeAs="dbRef",
 *     inversedBy="references",
 *     cascade={"persist"}
 * )
 */
protected DocumentInterface $target;
```

How can I apply the built-in SearchFilter from Api_Platform to return all items with a matching dbRef and what would the adequate Request look like?

Comment: I thought I might be able to filter available items by querying by IRI, but when I specify the filter with
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: [
    'target' => 'exact'
])]
and add &target=<Reference IRI>, I retrieve an error message:

ApiPlatform\\Core\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\MongoDbOdm\\Filter\\SearchFilter::getClassMetadata(): Argument #1 ($resourceClass) must be of type string, null given

Answer (score 0):

I have now implemented a workaround myself by creating a custom dbRef-Filter to add a filter for existing references to the AggregationBuilder.

```
$aggregationBuilder->match()->field($property)->references($document);
```